# Why cannot I see any .asc file when i download the package?

Tags: support, verification

I wish to verify the signatures of Tor, but when I download the package I only have the `.exe` file to extract, I don't see any `.asc` file. I was following the short user manual for verify the signatures, but seems I cannot do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: There's a link called (sig) that will take you to a new page with the PGP signature, simply file save as.... within your browser and it will automatically name it as it should.

Comment: Your answer brings nothing new. If you want to support the previous ones, you should give them an upvote when [you will have enough reputation.](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Answer (score 5):

When you download Tor or the Browser Bundles directly from [Tor Project Download Page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) you can find a link called (sig) this is the asc file you need for verifying
 the downloaded packages.

Answer (score 4):

The signature is not bundled with the archive; it can be found on the Tor Project website in the same place as the download (just append `.asc` to the end of the archive's path or look for the `sig` link under the download link).

See [here](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/3.5/) for a full list of TBB 3.5 archives and signatures.